# I can't get a p-value higher than 0.05 with R

Tags: r, p-value

I'm following the Pizza example from here: https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/what-a-p-value-tells-you-about-statistical-data/

```
x1 <- runif(30, 15, 30) #(so 30 deliveries between 15 and 30 minutes)
x2 <- runif(30, 10, 20) #(so 30 deliveries between 10 and 20 minutes)
```

> ```
> #t.test(x1,x2) data:  x1 and x2 t = 7.1688, df = 48.866, p-value =
> #3.687e-09 mean of x mean of y
> # 21.35968  15.39286
> ```

I can see with the mean of y the delivery time is inside 30m so I failed to reject H0 but the p-value result says otherwise.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Klumbard you gave me some light, the t.test you provided me clearly show a p-value of 1, so rejecting the null hypothesis. I think I'm lost because my teacher passed the following situation: Company A created a new drug that should reduce fever on patients. - __$\mathcal{H}_0$:__ The drug fails to reduce fever on patients
- __$\mathcal{H}_1$:__ The drug reduces fever on patients x1 <- runif(30, 37.9, 38.8) x2 <- runif(30, 36.0, 38.2) I was able to do it without difficulties and found the p-value that rejects the H0, but to see if I got it correctly I've tried to reproduce a scenario where the

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please check https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour. You shouldn't post replies as 'answers' but instead as either comments or edits to the question

Answer (score 2):

You are testing whether values taken from the range [15 30] have different means from values taken from the range [10 20].

Putting aside whether a t-test is the best way to test here, clearly the means are different: in one case the expected mean is 22.5, in the other case the expected mean is 15. If you sample from those two distributions and compare the means, you should reject the null hypothesis that the means are equal as long as you have enough samples.

I think where you have gone wrong is that you are thinking you are testing something besides what I wrote here, otherwise you should definitely be getting small p-values with sample sizes like you are using: you are not testing a null hypothesis of <30 minutes, you are testing a null hypothesis of mean(15 to 30 minutes) = mean(10 to 20 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

The null hypothesis of `t.test(x1,x2)` is that the samples `x1` and `x2` come from (normal) distributions with the same means. Clearly this isn't the case. The mean of `x1`'s distribution is 22.5 and the mean of `x2`'s distribution is 15. So I don't know why you'd expect not to reject the null hypothesis.